# Delphi TeeChart doesnt rotate labels

Tags: delphi, charts, teechart, fastreport

I tried rotating labels by settings the `Chart.BottomAxis.LabelsAngle := 45` but that doesn't work no matter to what value i change it i want my labels to be displayed vertically because not some labels overlap one another:
[image]

my settings are:

[image]

any ideas of how to fix this issue

P.S my chart is stacked

**What i have already tried:**
tried changing the LabelsAngle property to 0,45,90,135 none seem to have any effect, the teechart version is the one that comes with Delphi, Currently using Delphi XE5.

**Chart is used in FastReport**

tried with non stacked chart and it seems to work upper stacked chart lower not stacked any idea what can cause this?:
[image]

Comment: That's odd... what if you double-click the chart and set the property in the chart's design-time editor?

Comment: I am settings the value in design time :)

Comment: *In the design-time editor* - not in the control properties pane.  You are showing the properties pane in your post.  The `LabelsAngle` property seems new in the pane (I only have XE2 but it's not there).  If, however, you double-click the chart you get a custom editor for the chart where you can also set this value.  As a second question, does it work if you set it programmatically at runtime?  This may just be a bug with the property streaming in the new version.

Comment: its a VCL and its used from FastReport if you add a chart object it should allow you to see this property on XE2 also. just click on Chart when in editor and go to BottomAxis there you will see the LabelAngle

Comment: Ah... I don't have FastReport `TfrxChart`.  I've updated the tags for you.

Comment: This works fine for me with TeeChart 2014.11.140512, which is the latest version available. Does this work fine using a TChart component without FastReports? You could also check if the free TeeChart update for XE5 Update 2 solves the problem for you: http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/29708

Comment: hmm strangely yes :) thanks post this as an answer and ill accept it

Comment: @AirWolf answer posted, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me with TeeChart 2014.11.140512, which is the latest version available. Does this work fine using a TChart component without FastReports? You could also check if the free TeeChart update for XE5 Update 2 solves the problem for you: cc.embarcadero.com/Item/29708

Answer (score -1):

If you are using MS Sans Serif you can try Tahoma.

Comment: changing the font doesn't help